# Reducing blur via GIMP command line

Tags: gimp, blur, image-editing

I should preface this by stating that I'm a developer, not a graphic designer. I have a need to programmatically reduce image/video blur and have seen evidence that GIMP supports blur reduction:

- [Reduce motion blur using the GIMP](http://www.instructables.com/id/Reduce-motion-blur-in-The-GIMP/); and
- [Smart Sharpening](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Smart_Sharpening/); etc.

I also see that GIMP has a "batch mode" command-line feature for doing bulk operations on lots of files at a time, and/or for typical shell/terminal usage.

I guess I'm wondering if any of these blur reduction/sharpening tools/utils are available on the GIMP command-line, where their documentation (if any exists) might be, and what some of the commands/arguments might look like.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple sharpening, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) has a `-sharpen` operator:

```
convert foobar.jpg -sharpen 0x1.0 foobar-sharpened.jpg
```

As usual with ImageMagick, this can of course be part of a more complex processing.

There is also a very complete suite of image filters called [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu). They can be used in a command line or as Gimp filters, so a good technique is to use them in Gimp to figure out the most suitable processing & settings and then run them in command line mode for "production".

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the features available in the UI are also available in batch mode.

**Example script** ([shamelessly stolen from here](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/))

```
(define (simple-unsharp-mask filename
         radius
         amount
         threshold)
 (let* ((image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)))
        (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
  (plug-in-unsharp-mask RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
   image drawable radius amount threshold)
  (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename filename)
  (gimp-image-delete image)))
```

If you put this in your scripts directory, you can run it like this:

```
gimp -i -b '(simple-unsharp-mask "foo.png" 5.0 0.5 0)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

To find out what commands you can use in scripts, open GIMP and click *Help > Procedure Browser*.

I personally find GIMP script-fu difficult to write (it looks like Python in a blender) and use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) instead.

**Edit**

"Python in a blender" is more formally known as TinyScheme.

Comment: You can write your Gimp scripts in Python, even for batch mode.

Comment: It's not "Python in a blender" - it is Scheme, TinyScheme to be precise.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher thanks for the correction. I actually wasn't sure what it was, but it looked unfriendly to me. Anytime I saw it, I'd say "nuts to that--I'll just use ImageMagick"

Comment: I like your style @Scribblemacher